# Sending a POST request using Request module but getting almost empty array of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API using the request module but when i console.log the data sent it seems only the `time`, `approved` status and `id` are sent which is by default from the model schema but the rest data are not sent. I need help.
This is what is sent
[image]
instead of something like this
[image]

console.log(req.body) when i send data with Postman
[image]

the request body when i send data with request module
[image]

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

//models config
let jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 category: String,
 description: String,
 type: String,
 url: String,
 email: String,
 apply: String,
 location: String,
 company: String,
 // path: String,
 approved: {type: Boolean, default: false},
 created: {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 1000}
})

let Job = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema);

module.exports = Job;
```

```js
//This is from another file :helpers
exports.createJob = (req, res) => {
    db.Job.create(req.body)
    .then((newJob) => {
        res.status(201).json(newJob)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err)
    })

}

//post
    app.get('/jobs/add', (req, res) => {
        res.render('add')
    })

    app.post('/jobs', (req, res)=>{
        // let formBody = {
     //                 title: req.title,
        //          category: req.category,
        //          description: req.body.description,
        //          type: req.body.type,
        //          url: req.body.url,
        //          email: req.bodyemail,
        //          apply: req.body.apply,
        //          location: req.body.location,
        //          company: req.body.company,
     //                 // path: fullPath,
     //                 createdAt: Date.now()
     //            };
        console.log()
        request.post({url:'http://localhost:3000/api/jobs/', form: {key:'value'}}, function optionalCallback(err, response, body) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
          }else{
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
            }
            return res.redirect('/jobs')
        });
    })
```

```html
<div class="add-container">
    <form name="myForm"  action="/jobs" method="POST" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Title(Junior/Graduate/Intern)</h2>
        <input type="text" name="job[title]" placeholder="e.g: Junior Front-End Developer" class="form-control" id="title" required="title">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Company Name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="e.g: Microsoft" class="form-control" required="company">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Job Description</h2>

        <textarea id="mytextarea" name="description" placeholder="e.g: We are looking for a Front-End developer with about a year of experience in HTML, CSS, javaScript. Knowledge in React/Vue/Angular is a plus." class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Apply by Website</h2>
        <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="e.g: https://wwww.example.com/jobs" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>How to Apply</h2>
        <input type="text" name="apply" placeholder="e.g: send your CV or Resume to..." class="form-control" required="apply">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h2>Company Location</h2>
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="e.g Lagos" class="form-control" required="location">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Apply by Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="e.g: job@gmail.com" required="email">
      </div>
     <!--  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Company logo</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" single class="form-control" id="file" required="file">
      </div> -->

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you posting your form body as? JSON? url encoded?

Comment: looks like you are trying to do formdata

Comment: I'm posting my body as url encoded. Yes i would like to do formdata but for now i just want to be able to post data

Answer (score 0):

remember to start app.js with body-parser urlencoded and json for json data
tested and works

```js
//in app.js
require("dotenv").config(); //to read env variable not needed
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URI; //from env variable
const Model = require('./models/model.model');

mongoose
  .connect(
    dbUrl,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connected"))
  .catch(error => console.log("Failed " + error));
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

**app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());**




  htmlObject = ` <div class="add-container">
  <form name="myForm"  action="/job" method="POST" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>Title(Junior/Graduate/Intern)</h2>
      <input type="text" name="job[title]" placeholder="e.g: Junior Front-End Developer" class="form-control" id="title" required="title">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>Company Name</h2>
      <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="e.g: Microsoft" class="form-control" required="company">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>Job Description</h2>
     
      <textarea id="mytextarea" name="description" placeholder="e.g: We are looking for a Front-End developer with about a year of experience in HTML, CSS, javaScript. Knowledge in React/Vue/Angular is a plus." class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>Apply by Website</h2>
      <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="e.g: https://wwww.example.com/jobs" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>How to Apply</h2>
      <input type="text" name="apply" placeholder="e.g: send your CV or Resume to..." class="form-control" required="apply">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>Company Location</h2>
      <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="e.g Lagos" class="form-control" required="location">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Apply by Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="e.g: job@gmail.com" required="email">
    </div>
   <!--  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Company logo</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" single class="form-control" id="file" required="file">
    </div> -->
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  `;


app.get('/add', (req,res)=>{
      res.send(htmlObject);
  });

app.post('/job', (req,res)=>{
  
  
  let model = new Model({
      title: req.body.title,
      category: req.body.category,
      description: req.body.description,
      type: req.body.type,
      url: req.body.url,
      email: req.body.email,
      apply: req.body.apply,
      location: req.body.location,
      company: req.body.company,
      path: req.body.path,
      createdAt: Date.now().toString()
  
  });
  
  model.save().then(data=>{
    res.json({message: 'success', data: data })

  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  })
module.exports = app;
//in models/model.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: Number},
  category: { type: Number},
  description: {type: String},
  type: {type: String},
  url: {type: String},
  email: {type: String},
  apply: {type: String},
  location: {type: String},
  company: {type: String},
  path: {type: String},
  createdAt: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("data", dataSchema);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a console.log in two places, after let data console.log(data), and in the callback function before console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) add console.log(res) and post that.

Comment: The issue is probably in your dB logic then. Can you post your mongoose model ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my example with a fully working answer, and an image to show it as well. Please compare with yours, make sure in your app is you have initialized body parser to include url encoded false and json (for the response)

Comment: Your example is a bit different from mine in that i'm trying to use the request module to post the request. Besides there's an api route already for the post request `exports.createJob = (req, res) => {
 db.Job.create(req.body)
 .then((newJob) => {
  res.status(201).json(newJob)
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  res.send(err)
 })

}` when i use postman to send the post request everything works fine as you can see in the second screen shot above. But im only having issues posting and getting the same data using the request module

Comment: well if you say it works in postman then presumably it should work as long as you are sending it in url.encoded, would you be able to send the console.log(req.body) from the route for the post request

Comment: The console.log(req.body) when using postman is what i sent previouslyin the second screenshot above. But when i send using the request module i get something like this `title: undfined, category: undefined` etc

Comment: right I meant before it actually does the creating in your jobs routes.  exports.createJob = (req, res) => {CONSOLE.LOG(req.body) ;db.Job.create(req.body) .then((newJob) => { res.status(201).json(newJob) }) .catch((err) => { res.send(err) }) }

Comment: I've added a the screenshots above. I get an empty object when i send data with the request module

Comment: Yes so, as I had said previously you aren’t submitting any data from your form... so edit your above code, where you put form:{value:key}. Make it form: {req.body}.

Comment: I've edited it to something different but now when i console.log i find all the fields are undefined. except the `Date` field which displays by default.